# collections.sort an CustomObject ArrayList which have multiple types

Tags: java

So I made a CustomObject:

```
class CustomObject {
        int v1;
        String v2;
        CustomObject(int v1, String v2) {
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
        }
    }
```

Then made a list:

```
List<CustomObject> myList = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
```

And then I added bunch of information into this list by using for

```
for(ITS NOT NECESSARY){
                CustomObject o1 = new CustomObject(AN INTEGER HERE,A STRING HERE);
                myList.add(o1);
}
```

And I want to order them by using Collectors.sort with order of v1(THE INTEGER ONE).Like the first one will be the element which has greatest value of v1,and so on..And I don't know how.I Looked up on Javadoc but did not found it
The code should be like this

```
Collections.sort(myList, v1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<CustomObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final CustomObject object1, final CustomObject object2) {
                return object1.v1 > object2.v1? -1 : object1.v1 < object2.v1 ? +1 : 0;
            }
        });
```